# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI with Wildfly and Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly

I just decided to start using Jboss and ran into some issues on configuration. I was hoping to find the solution here.

I am using intellij 14 Ultimate and below are some screen shots of my set up.

[image]

[image]

```
/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/util.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper /private/var/folders/82/0w1gp6xx3sl3hptcc5pqsxj00000gn/T/classpath0.tmp com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 53199 com.intellij.javaee.oss.jboss.agent.JBoss71Agent
[2015-08-21 01:03:33,576] Artifact offers:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Detected server admin port: 9990
Detected server http port: 8080
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /wildfly-9.0.1.Final

  JAVA: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

13:03:32,399 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.4.3.Final
13:03:33,176 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
13:03:33,375 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) starting
13:03:36,270 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
13:03:36,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 12) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'job-repository-type' in the resource at address '/subsystem=batch' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
13:03:36,454 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
13:03:36,644 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
13:03:36,657 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
13:03:36,820 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
13:03:36,836 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 4 core threads with 32 task threads based on your 2 available processors
13:03:36,860 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
13:03:36,892 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
13:03:36,955 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
13:03:36,955 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
13:03:36,959 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
13:03:36,983 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
13:03:37,002 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
13:03:37,002 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
13:03:37,010 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
13:03:37,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.2.4.Final)
13:03:37,187 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.2.Final
13:03:37,477 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
13:03:37,480 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
13:03:37,488 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:03:37,625 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path /wildfly-9.0.1.Final/welcome-content
13:03:37,644 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
13:03:37,717 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
13:03:37,981 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /127.0.0.1:8080
13:03:38,321 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /wildfly-9.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments
13:03:38,767 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
13:03:38,816 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 5.0.0.Final
13:03:39,348 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
13:03:39,348 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
13:03:39,349 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) started in 8364ms - Started 203 of 379 services (210 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
Connected to server
[2015-08-21 01:03:40,302] Artifact offers:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
13:03:40,550 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "offers_war_exploded" (runtime-name: "offers_war_exploded.war")
13:03:41,677 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
13:03:41,952 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
13:03:42,036 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.11-jbossorg-1 20150505-1501 for context '/offers_war_exploded'
13:03:43,576 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'offers'
13:03:43,579 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) FrameworkServlet 'offers': initialization started
13:03:43,601 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'offers-servlet': startup date [Fri Aug 21 13:03:43 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
13:03:43,640 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/offers-servlet.xml]
13:03:43,957 INFO  [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
13:03:43,963 INFO  [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
13:03:44,127 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
13:03:44,136 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@737dec13: defining beans [offersController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
13:03:44,274 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) Mapped "{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.caveofprogramming.spring.web.controllers.OffersController.showHome()
13:03:44,304 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
13:03:44,871 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) FrameworkServlet 'offers': initialization completed in 1292 ms
13:03:44,872 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /offers_war_exploded
13:03:44,892 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "offers_war_exploded" (runtime-name : "offers_war_exploded.war")
[2015-08-21 01:03:44,923] Artifact offers:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-08-21 01:03:44,923] Artifact offers:war exploded: Deploy took 4,621 milliseconds
13:03:45,415 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/offers_war_exploded/home] in DispatcherServlet with name 'offers'
13:03:45,953 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-3) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/offers_war_exploded/home] in DispatcherServlet with name 'offers'
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>spring-tutorial-50</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>offers</display-name>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

-------UPDATE ONE-------------

I am a little confused here.

The error said:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/offers_war_exploded/home] in DispatcherServlet with name 'offers'
```

So I decided to do the following:

```
<url-pattern>/offers_war_exploded/home/*</url-pattern>
```

Full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>spring-tutorial-50</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>offers</display-name>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/offers_war_exploded/home/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now the artifact is deployed successfully but in the browser I get:

[image]

Comment: If the `offers` servlet should receive all the requests, you need a * in its *url-mapping*: `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

Comment: Yes I did forget that but that did not fix the issue. Thank you are seeing that.